# How do I run interactive shell such as "exec tclsh" from inside tclsh?

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to run some interactive shell from inside tclsh? Obviously it's easy to run an interactive shell such as bash or tclsh from inside bash, but I have not found a way to do the reverse.

If I run "exec tclsh" or "exec bash" from inside tclsh I don't get a prompt until I type "exit" and hit enter, or I use "ctrl-C" which kills the parent tclsh.

I would prefer not to use an external package, if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Provided you don't want to pass values* (other than the exit code) *back to the calling Tcl code* you can do it pretty easily by redirecting the standard channels so that Tcl doesn't capture them:

```
exec tclsh <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

This will work for pretty much any subprocess (I've just tested it with `vi`) and is what tclsh actually does magically for you in interactive mode if it decides to try running a subprocess.

If you want to do anything more complex than that, you probably need to look into using Expect as there's a very long list of tricky gotchas otherwise.

Comment: This worked so good I spun around in my chair.